# How to define date range format for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have a `biblatex` entry with `eventdate` defined as:

```
eventdate = {2012-09-01/2012-09-04}
```

Using the `apa` style, which does not have definitions for a *date range*, `\printeventdate` results in

> September 1, 2012– 4

How do I format it such that it produces:

> 1-4 September, 2012

for

```
eventdate = {2012-09-01/2012-09-04}
```

and

> 28 September, 2012 - 3 October, 2012

for

```
eventdate = {2012-09-28/2012-10-03}
```

?

In another words, the day and month need to be reversed, and it needs to decide whether the month and year are both the same, if so compress the day field such that `eventday-eventendday eventmonth, eventyear`. Otherwise use `eventday eventmonth, eventyear-eventendday eventendmonth, eventendyear`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
%Add eventdate
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifthenelse{\NOT\iffieldundef{title}\OR\boolean{bbx:titleinauthpos}}{\newunit}{\setunit{\addspace}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{editor+trans}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
  \printeventdate%
  \setunit*{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addinfo}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{series}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \printfield[apacase]{eventtitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{venue}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock 
  \usebibmacro{origyear}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:finpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{anon1,
  author = {Anon, A. N.},
  title = {A very interesting paper},
  booktitle = {Proc. {UKACC} International Conference on Control},
  date = {2010-09},
  eventdate = {2010-09-07/2010-09-10},
  venue = {Coventry},
  pages = {1--3}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> Anon, A. N. (2010, September). A very interesting paper. In Proc. UKACC
>   international conference on control, September
>   7, 2010– 10 (pp. 1–3). Coventry.

Comment: Sorry it seems that asserting the default permeable option of `eventdate=comp` to `biblatex` fixes the problem. I don't know why since that should be the default!

Comment: `biblatex-apa` applies the custom `apalong` format to all dates. Default style settings in the `biblatex` manual generally don't carry over to style packages. For a question like this one it is important to create a MWE using the style and language in your actual document.

Comment: I see, the MWE does include the `babel` and `declarelanguagemapping` commands to illustrate the problem. In anycase since `eventdate=comp` fixes the above, this question can be closed.

Comment: I have also noticed `biblatex-apa` incorrectly handles `booktitle` by preceeding with "In" and `eventdate` field for `inproceedings` in terms of both the bug mentioned in the question here and that it is not printed. I have email these concerns to the maintainer.